# Incorrect Syntax when creating table from textbox name

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I was trying to create a table based on the name given in textbox1 .I am getting error in the following code :

> Incorrect syntax near 'Ramesh'.

Here Ramesh was the value in textbox.

```
string Customername = Textbox1.text 
SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE '" + CustomerName + "' (ItemCode int,Quantity int,PricePerQuantity int,Brand char(50),Discount int , DateTime datetime)",connection
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need single quotes for your table name.

```
SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + CustomerName + " (ItemCode int,Quantity int,PricePerQuantity int,Brand char(50),Discount int , DateTime datetime)",connection);
```

But weird part, don't use `SqlCommand` for MySQL. Use [`MySqlCommand`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommand.html) and related class.

Also I would say that use parameterize queries but since you *can't* parameterize column name, and looks like you get it as an input, use strong validation or use whitelisting before you put it in your query.

You can read: [The BobbyTables culture](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/)

Comment: Thanks . Yes I tried using this , the error went off but the table was not created in database .

Answer (score 1):

remove `'` from sides of the table name in query.

```
string Customername = Textbox1.text 
SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + CustomerName + " (ItemCode int,Quantity int,PricePerQuantity int,Brand char(50),Discount int , DateTime datetime)",connection
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause of the error is that you should not put *table name* into apostrophes. Something like this:

```
// put IDisposable into using
using (SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand(
  // Keep SQL readable; "$" - C# 6.0 feature
  $@"CREATE TABLE {Textbox1.text}(
       ItemCode int,
       Quantity int, 
       PricePerQuantity int,
       Brand char(50),
       Discount int, 
       DateTime datetime)", 
  connection)) {

  cmd7.ExecuteNonQuery(); // execute and create the table
}
```